# Error: Cannot find module './_Map' reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install, npm-start

After I create my react project with `npx create-react-app my-app` I run `npm start` and get this error as you can see below

node version: 12.16.1

npm version: 6.13.4

```
Error: Cannot find module './_Map'
```

Comment: Share your code and folder directory screenshot where './Map' js is contain

Comment: In this link I have 2 images from my error https://gofile.io/?c=YVUums